# Remote Desktop Software - TeamViewer comparison?

Tags: remote-assistance, teamviewer

<sup>Preliminary Note: After reading what I wrote below, I would like to stress that this ain't a TeamViewer ad. It's just that all other tools that I checkked online seem to miss one feature or the other. :-)</sup>

OK, so I'm currently trying to get a picture of [available solutions for remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).

I have found (through personal usage) that [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) pretty much ticks all boxes that I personally would want from any remoting tool. (Specifically it's setup is amazingly trivial.)

It supports a wide range of platforms and it's even free for private use, so I'm really quite OK with it.

I would be interested if anyone knows of other tools that ticks as many boxes as TeamViewer seems to do.

Comment: There's a great comparison chart over at wikipedia -- Oh wait, you already found/linked it... :)  Voted to close: "I use XYZ, what do you use?"  "What XYZ is 'the best'?"

Comment: @techie007 : The question *specifically* asks about differences btw. TeamViewer and other similar tools. Plus: Personally I'd scrap the "great" from any description of the comparison chart at Wikipedia. It does a decent job of showing what products there are, but otherwise it doesn't list much that could not be quickly learned from surfing to the vendor sites. For me, Kyle's answer is very useful!

Comment: No, it specifically asks for a comparison, and by the end is specifically asking if there's other tools that 'tick as many boxes as TV seems to do'.  I don't think you're going to find many other software packages that aren't already on that list.  But mainly, this question (IMO) borders on off-topic as defined by the FAQ (you're asking for opinions on things already known). But that's why it takes 5 votes to close.

Comment: @techie007: No worries :-) (Aside: I disagree that I ask about things already known. Certainly not about any "known" things that are easy to find.) Anyways - thanks for specifying your reasons for your close vote.

Comment: no worries here either. :)  By 'already known' I meant you already had that chart which provides about as good a comparison as you'll find. :)  My REAL answer is, give up on all that crap and pay for a Bomgar box. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an avid Team viewer user and suggest it at every opportunity, but as far as features are concerned [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/access/freedom/5/?wt.srch=1&utpk=LogMeIn&destination=/welcome/access/freedom/5/&originid=57021&ef_id=IEJNd5tH-SkAAIk1:20110309152247:s) does just about everything Team viewer does and more.

EDIT: I was asked to add some differences so I'll start with a few I noticed and add more as I dig deeper for differences. Everyone else feel free to edit my post with other features and mods feel free to change to CW if you see fit.

- Teamviewer has the ability to black the other screen out so the users can't see what your are doing.
- Logmein pro has wake on LAN support, this is not a feature in version 5 of
  Team viewer. I don't know about V6 we
  haven't updated our enterprise
  license yet.
- Teamviewer adds the little quick share button at the top of task bars
  (pictured below) so you can quickly
  share one screen with a colleague or
  friend without sharing your whole
  desktop.

[image]

Comment: Seems very nice. Less platforms, but I guess most users would be satisfied with being able to support Win+Mac ... LogMeIn runs in the browser - so it will run on Firefox+Linux ??

Comment: I won't bother posting an answer because mine would be this word-for-word.  We use LogMeIn Rescue for end-user support and it's just got SO MUCH FUNCTIONALITY (especially if you're dealing with users with multiple displays, which all of ours are.)

Comment: "about everything Team viewer does and more" ... any specific "more" in mind? I don't need many advanced features, so it would be interesting to hear of some nifty feature one or the other has/hasn't.

Comment: @martin honestly I couldn't find anything major, I put that there in case I missed something but as far as I can tell they do exactly the same things. I can add the little things I noticed thought...

Comment: Do the pro versions of TeamViewer have that nice functionality where you can see Event Viewer/running processes/etcetc in that neat little interface or something comparable?

Comment: @shinrai no it doesn't have that feature, the pro version of team viewer is exactly the same as the free you just can't use free in commercial environments. Good catch I completely forgot about that feature, feel free to add it.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Netviewer](http://www.netviewer.com/) for remote support which does pretty much everything i need. Netviewer was recently accuired by Citrix though.

Comment: Seems to be a decent tool too. Though it apparently "only" supports Win+Mac.

Comment: Is the fact that it was acquired by Citrix a problem?

Comment: @Martin - It just may mean it's not long for this world.  I can't really see a place for it in their product lineup.

Answer (score 0):

we use logmeinrescue at my work really good client i find easy to use aswell yo dont have to be a computer geek to use it. other one ssi have come across are Quick connect. gotomeeting. but personaly i would recommend logmein you can have the free or paid for account

Comment: just remembered logmein console can only be used on pc but can access macs and pcs